# Should controllers be abbreviated? Ie CountryController vs CountriesController

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am wondering if there is any written standard on the naming of controllers in asp.net core/mvc/api?

I am not really finding anything.

Thanks

Comment: It's really subjective. If you want your url to be "countries", then name it `CountriesController`, otherwise name it `CountryController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard is implied with REST Api Design standard.

That means if you are providing a REST point for the handling of multiple countries you would create a CountriesController which would be routed to by asp from https://localhost:443/countries/.

Answer (score 0):

The convention is name it according to the route it should have, which in case of an API should be `countries` to conform to REST principles. However, that convention is based on utilizing a default route which simply maps whatever comes before `Controller` as part of the path. With attribute routing, or even simply just custom standard routing, you can make the route whatever you want, which then means that the controller could be named whatever you want, as it's no longer being utilized directly as part of the route.

Long and short, `CountriesController` is probably *better*, since it aligns better to the route it should have, but ultimately, there's no hard and fast rule here. As with most questions like this, the only answer is the one that makes the most sense for you, your team, and your application, which none of us here can dictate for you.